# Mysql compressed file .gz unable to extract file part

Tags: bash, scripts, sql, magento

I have written a bash script for backing up my sql database.

```
#!/bin/bash
#START
DBNAME=test_uat
host=127.0.0.1
username=root
DATE=`date +"%Y%m%d"`
SQLFILE=spen_db-${DATE}
mysqldump -u $username -p $DBNAME --routines | gzip -9  > $Backup_path.sql.gz
#END
```

I get a .sql.gz file which is part file.

Unable to download the same, it says corrupt archive.

Comment: I debug cases like this as follows: store the command to be executed in a variable: `stmt="mysqldump --opt $username -p ...etc"`, see what it looks like: `echo $stmt` and then execute it: `$stmt`. You will be able to figure out where the error is.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Jos, i found there was /r which i was able to remove using sed cmd and now i get .gz file around some 1gb which is part file...y so...im not able to download the same

Answer (score 0):

It should not matter if you have mapped 127.0.0.1 to mysite.com, the most common problem I have had with Mysql backup script for 20 years it that there are no spaces allowed between "-u" and the username, and between "-p" and the password.

Comment: I guess u may be right, but thats the actual problem for my scenario? i tried removing the space between -u and username, i face the same issue

Comment: It doesn't allow a space after `-p`,  but a space after `-u` doesn't seem to matter.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that combination **'your_user'@'localhost'** doesn't exist in the table **mysql.user** 
or you enter wrong password